# Proofs on Irrational/Rational Real Numbers

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I'm working through a book on Abstract Algebra and I'm at the section reading into Rings. As with all textbooks they pose questions without solutions and I have solutions to two problems I was hoping to have looked over.

Problem 1:

Consider a set of real numbers of the form

$x = a + bp$

Where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $p \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Then $\forall a,b \neq 0 \quad x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Employ Proof by contradiction,

Let $x$ be Rational, i.e. $x = \frac{c}{d}$ with $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

$d \neq 0$ and $\gcd(c,d) = 1$

Then

$a + bp = \frac{c}{d}$

As $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$  Let $a = \frac{e}{f}$ , $b = \frac{g}{h}$ with $e,f,g,h \in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $f,h \neq 0$ and $\gcd(e,f) = \gcd(g,h) = 1$

Then

$a + bp = \frac{c}{d} $

Becomes

$\frac{e}{f} + \frac{g}{h}p = \frac{c}{d}$

$\frac{g}{h}p = \frac{c}{d} - \frac{e}{f}$

$p = \frac{h}{g} \left(\frac{c}{d} - \frac{e}{f}\right) = \frac{h\left(fc - ed\right)}{gdf} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Which is false as $p \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Thus by Proof by Contradiciton $x = a + bp \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ , $a,b \neq 0$

Problem 2:

If $x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Then for $k \in \mathbb{Q}, k \neq 0$ we have $kx \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Employ Proof by Contradiction.

Let $kx$ be Rational, i.e. $kx = \frac{c}{d}$ with $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

$d \neq 0$ and $\gcd(c,d) = 1$

As $k \in \mathbb{Q}$ Let $k = \frac{e}{f}$ with $e,f \in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $\gcd(e,f) = 1$

Then

$ kx = \frac{e}{f}x = \frac{c}{d}$

Thus

$x = \frac{c}{d} \frac{f}{e} = \frac{cf}{de} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Which is false as $x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Thus by Proof by Contradiction $kx \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Q}$, $k \neq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof by contradiction seems fine.

One might present it more compactly:

For example for problem $1$, If $a+bp=x$, then $bp=x-a \in \mathbb{Q}$ since rational number is closed under subtraction and $p=\frac{x-a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$  is rational since division of non-zero rational number gives us rational number. This contradicts to $p$ is irrational.

Comment: Cheers mate. Appreciate the response. At this point I'm happy it's correct but will certainly try to make it easier on myself in the future as you have put here.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are correct, but unnecessarily complicated. You already know that $\mathbb Q$ is a field. If $a+bp=c$, with $c\in\mathbb Q$, then $$p=\frac{c-a} {b}\in\mathbb Q,$$ a contradiction.

Similarly, if $kp=c$, then $p=c/k$.

Comment: Cheers mate. Appreciate the response. At this point I'm happy it's correct but will certainly try to make it easier on myself in the future as you have given.